# Angular JS embedding same template in many other templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS with a test app(started with AngularJS seed project), which involves user session. Once user logged in, there are multiple views. I am using different partials for them. Right now my problem is, I want to show user name and logout link in all the views inside the app.

The only way i can think of to achieve that is, add required html for the user name & logout button in all the views & add required data in the scope in each controller. 
I believe that's not a right way to do it.

I know about [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki). But I am not able to make use of it.

With router or with some other approach, I would like to achieve something like this:

### Main html:

```
<div ng-view><!-- Main DIV -->
    <div><!-- Login partial comes here, if not logged in or else app partial will be displayed--></div>
</div>
```

### App Partial:

```
<div>
  <div class='userInfo'><!-- userInfoPartialTemplate here --> </div>
  <div><!-- any other app partial template will be filled according to the url --></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions or links would be appreciative!

Thanks!

Comment: ngInclude might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @jaux: No, Its not working out. It loks like `ng-include` only works if you put it in main html page. But, my requirement is to use it inside another template. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I just tried it in a fiddle. Not working.

Comment: wrapping the `src` with single quotes did it :)

Comment: Great! I have created an answer with more information you may be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

`ngInclude` directive is what you need <kbd>[doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude)</kbd>. You can try to use `ngInclude` like this:

```
<div>
  <div class='userInfo'><!-- userInfoPartialTemplate here --> </div>
  <div ng-include="'your-app-partial.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Notice your template URL is wrapped by a single quote!

Moreover, you can use angular expression to specify the template URL in `ngInclude`. For example, you have a scope variable to hold the template URL, you don't know what the value would be beforehand, your controller looks like:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.subTemplate = 'your-app-partial.html'; // I use static string here for simplicity, but it could be anything that gives you the template URL...
}
```

The `subTemplate` variable holds the URL value of your template, now you should have your HTML look like:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class='userInfo'><!-- userInfoPartialTemplate here --> </div>
  <div ng-include="subTemplate"></div>
</div>
```

This [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VZ6RB92ccQBEFWc3tqP4) is created to demonstrate the idea.